# Meteor: redirect a user if already logged in

Tags: meteor

I'm using [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router), and I'd like to redirect a user to `/user` if he requests `/` and he is already logged in.

As expected, this just renders the `user_index` template rather than changing the URL:

```
Meteor.Router.add
  '/': -> if Meteor.userId() then 'user_index' else 'index'
```

I want to do something like this:

```
Meteor.Router.add
  '/': -> if Meteor.userId() then Meteor.Router.to '/user' else 'index'
```

---

#### update 6/4/14:

This question is no longer relevant, and [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) should be used instead.

Comment: meteor-router is deprecated. Use iron-router instead.

Comment: Indeed. I updated the question to make this clear.

Comment: Actually the question is really useful, it appears high in search results, it just needed a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/issues/30) it looks like redirects are not part of meteor-router, and may not be. For now I ended up working around the issue. If the project changes to accommodate redirects I'll update my answer, or someone else can post another answer.

**update 1/23/13:**

I switched to using [mini-pages](https://github.com/cmather/meteor-mini-pages), which correctly deals with this case and includes a lot of great functionality like layouts.

Comment: mini-router has (also) gracefully bowed out in favour of iron-router

Answer (score 3):

meteor-router is now [deprecated](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router#note). Instead use [iron-router](https://atmospherejs.com/package/iron-router) which can redirect based on logged in status using:

```js
Router.configure({layoutTemplate: 'mainLayout'});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('splash', {path: '/'});
  this.route('home');
});

var mustBeSignedIn = function(pause) {
  if (!(Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())) {
    Router.go('splash');
    pause();
  }
};

var goToDashboard = function(pause) {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Router.go('home');
    pause();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {except: ['splash']});
Router.onBeforeAction(goToDashboard, {only: ['splash']});
```

Example taken from: [Meteor.js - Check logged in status before render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139627/meteor-js-check-logged-in-status-before-render)

--OR--

Use the [accounts-entry](http://atmospherejs.com/package/accounts-entry) package. From [their site](http://github.differential.io/accounts-entry/):

> **Ensuring signed in users for routes**
>
> Use AccountsEntry.signInRequired(this) to require signed in users for
>   a route. Stick that in your before hook function and it will redirect
>   to sign in and stop any rendering. Accounts Entry also tracks where
>   the user was trying to go and will route them back after sign in.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a `filter` -- here is a sample from the [docs](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router):

```
Meteor.Router.filters({
    'checkLoggedIn': function(page) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            return 'loading';
        } else if (Meteor.user()) {
            return page;
        } else {
            return 'signin';
        }
    }
});

// applies to all pages
Meteor.Router.filter('checkLoggedIn');
```

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with filters. This example only renders the `signin` template and does not change the URL. I've also tried adding a call to `Meteor.Router.to` in a filter and that didn't work either.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but because Router uses `pushState` to change the URL, you could possible [add it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) in the `filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor Router lets you directly access the response object, so you can just do a 302 redirect. Something like the following will work:

```
Meteor.Router.add("/test/:_id", (id) ->
  this.response.writeHead '302', {'Location': '/blah/' + id}
)
```

Comment: This is on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a standard filter and wrapping the redirect in a defer object.

```
Meteor.Router.filters({
requireLogin: function(page) {
    if(! (Meteor.loggingIn()|| Meteor.user()) ){
        Meteor.defer(function () {
            Meteor.Router.to('/login');
        });
    }
    return page;
}

Meteor.Router.filter('requireLogin', {except: 'login'});
```