# Meteor.js - Check logged in status before render

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

First off lets just start with the fact that I am a complete noob with Meteor. Now that that is out of the way let the problem begin...

I have two pages, a splash page at '/' and a home page at '/home'.  I am using iron-router for the routing.  Now If I am not logged in and on the splash page and login I have it redirecting to the home page this works.  Now if I close my browser and reopen and goto the '/' it loads for a few seconds then realizes that I am actually still logged in and then redirects me to '/home'.

My question is how to I get rid of this initial showing on the '/' when I am already logged in?  I only want to show that page to people not signed in.  Here is the code that I have in my router:

```
    Router.configure({layoutTemplate: 'mainLayout'});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('splash', {path: '/'});
  this.route('home');
});

var mustBeSignedIn = function(pause) {
  if (!(Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())) {
    Router.go('splash');
    pause();
  }
};

var goToDashboard = function(pause) {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Router.go('home');
    pause();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {except: ['splash']});
Router.onBeforeAction(goToDashboard, {only: ['splash']});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: remember to add this.next() after upgrade meteor > 1.0 more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629835/meteor-v-1-0-and-ironrouter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `fast-render` might be a solution. Just run

```
mrt add fast-render
```

Check [this great article](http://meteorhacks.com/instant-login-for-meteor-with-fast-render.html) on this topic.

Comment: This is perfect.  Installed, quick reboot of the server and all is as it should be!   Thank you so much.